# Javascript Focus and Blur

Tags: javascript, events, focus, addeventlistener, onblur

Every thing works fine except for the 'blur', for some reason I only get feedback when no characters are inputed, but as soon as I input a username that's less than five the checkUsername function that's attached to the 'blur' will not send any feedback(Also I have no error messages within my developer tool).

```
function checkUsername(){
    var username=el.value;
    if(username<5){
        elMsg.className='warning';
        elMsg.textContent='Not  long enough...';
    }else{
        elMsg.textContent='';
    }
}

function tipUsername(){
    elMsg.className='tip';
    elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be at least 5 characters';
}

var el=document.getElementById('username');
var elMsg=document.getElementById('feedback');

el.addEventListener('focus',tipUsername,false);
el.addEventListener('blur',checkUsername,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for the length of a String, use `"someString".length`:

```
/* ... */
if(username.length < 5){
/* ... */
```

#### Demo

```js
function checkUsername(){
    var username=el.value;
    if(username.length < 5){
        elMsg.className='warning';
        elMsg.textContent='Not  long enough...';
    }else{
        elMsg.textContent='';
    }
}

function tipUsername(){
    elMsg.className='tip';
    elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be at least 5 characters';
}

var el=document.getElementById('username');
var elMsg=document.getElementById('feedback');

el.addEventListener('focus',tipUsername,false);
el.addEventListener('blur',checkUsername,false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter a username..." />
<div id="feedback"></div>
```